# Bootstrap data-toggle , data-target & href attributes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap when I use the data-toggle & data-target attributes my href seems not to work does anyone know a way around this echo'Change'

Comment: Please provide a plunkr/jsfiddle so we can help you figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

When `data-target="link"` and `data-toggle="class"` are set, bootstrap.js uses them to override the default href attribute. Setting the href to a static link will give a noscript browser something to go to.

The standard HTML markup for an anchor tag is:

```
<a href="link.html">LINK</a>
```

which is what a noscript browser will see, because it will ignore the data-* values.

Answer (score 1):

For me there was no issue.

```
<div class="panel">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" data-parent="#panel" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aa">Collapse</a>
  <div id="aa" class="collapse in">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaggggggggg hhhhhhhhhh iii ii jjjjjjj kkkkkkk lllllllllll lllllllll mmmmmm mmmm ooooop</div>
</div>
```

Here my anchor tag takes me to google.com after collapsing the `#aa`

Answer (score 0):

data-target attributes use data-target="_blank"  below full code

`" data-target="_blank">`
[source code](https://www.findinall.com/blog/bootstrap-data-toggle-data-target-href-attributes/)